# jhipster project is broken after upgrade

Tags: jhipster

My jhipster project was working fine before.  Past two days it is acting funny.  There is some version changes causing these issues.

Initially I got the following error in console, when I tried navigating to different page :

> NavigationError(id: 2, url: '/ext-task-group-list', error:
>   InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character)

In an effort to try to fix this problem, I ran

> jphister upgrade

the upgrade is successful.  However, mvnw command is not starting the server.  Instead it is compiling the project and comes out successfully.

Couldnt find any resource in the net.

Anyone have fix for these two issues, pls share.

Answer (score 0):

Start by doing a mvnw -X to see all the debug errors. That will give you more detail that you can go by

Comment: -X didnot help.  there were debug stmts.  however, control came out after successful build.

I tried "mvnw spring-boot:run", same result.

Comment: Ohh I think see what you are saying. Are you saying that the command produces a successful build with no errors but it really should be staying on and running a server rather compiling and closing?

Comment: I had this happen to me before. I remember looking at the -X debug lines in detail and found something wrong. I think it had to do with maven and the libraries it were trying to download along with proxy issues.